# how to validate geojson format in django rest framework serializer class

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, gis

I want to validate geoJson format in Django rest serializer

JSON like below

"type": "Feature",
"geometry": {
"type": "Point",
"coordinates": [125.6, 10.1]
},
"properties": {
"name": "Dinagat Islands"
}
}

thanks

Comment: deserialization means converting JSON back to a model instance. you can use a Model serializer to do that.

Comment: I want to validate geojson

Comment: are you working with `PointFields` only?

Comment: no, all geometry type may be imported